# Excel Formula Equations

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to get Excel to formulate an equation but if the value is 0 to leave the space blank or even have a - in it or something.

```
IE: =D7*4+100
```

Which if D7 is blank will still yield 100. But I want the result to be blank or I would even settle for a dash (-).

I tried playing with the IF function but cant get it to work.

```
IE: =IF(d7=0,"-"),d7*4+100
```

But don't know how to properly format it. Anyone know how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out for size:

```
=IF(D7="","",D7*4+100)
```

Or if there's an actual 0 in D7:

```
=IF(D7=0,"",D7*4+100)
```

Comment: It was the "" I did'nt get right. I didnt know that you could use that to represent "blank". Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your bracket is in the wrong place it should be:

```
=IF(D7=0,"-",D7*4+100)
```